# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

When I run this code, I get an error of cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

I have tried moving around the functions, but the error persists.

```
 const users = [{age: 45, height: 5.6, weight: 76, name:'David', country: 'Nigeria', id: '85eir7e0hj'}];

  const select = document.querySelector('.select-text');
  const bmiButton = document.querySelector('#oracle');

  const getSelectedUser = (userId) => {
    return user = users.find(({ id }) => userId === id);

  };

  const displaySelectedUser = ({ target }) => {
    const user = getSelectedUser(target.value);
    const properties = Object.keys(user);
    properties.forEach((prop) => {
      const el = document.querySelector(`[data-${prop}-value]`);
      if(el !== null) el.textContent = user[prop];
    })
  };

  const letsCalculateBMI = () => {

  };

  const powerupTheUI = () => {
    select.addEventListener('change', displaySelectedUser);
    bmiButton.addEventListener('click', letsCalculateBMI)
  }

  const displayUsers = (users) => {
      users.forEach((user) => {
      const opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value = user.id;
      opt.textContent = user.name;
      select.appendChild(opt);
    })
  } 
  const fetchAndDisplayUsers = () => {
    users.push({
      age: 40,
      weight: 75,
      height: 6,
      country: 'Nigeria',
      name: 'Charles Odili',
      id: 'dfhb454768DghtF'
    });

    displayUsers(users);
  };

  const startApp = () => {
    powerupTheUI();
    fetchAndDisplayUsers();
  };


  startApp();
```

Comment: I don't see `map` being used anywhere in your code. Are you sure it's this code that is causing the error?

Comment: It was. Apparently, some other unknown file running on a different tab was the culprit.

Answer (score -1):

Something is retrieving the `.map` attribute from a null variable. It is not anything in the presented code: as comments noted, there is no `map` in your code.

Indeed, **your code appears to run correctly** by itself. I opened a random webpage, changed one HTML element to `class="select-text"` and another to `id="oracle"`, and pasted your code into the console. Clicking on the `#oracle` element caused data from your object to be added to the `.select-text`.

If you cannot get the line/source of the error, try the following (one at a time):

- running the code on another page without whatever other JavaScript may be running on the original,
- adding logging statements throughout your code (to see where other code may be executing and interfering), and
- disabling browser extensions, changing browsers, otherwise eliminating other factors that could be affecting your environment.

Comment: Had something to do with another code interfering with it. Closing othere tabs snd clearing browser's cache solved it. Thank you.